# Are there any limitations in IIS on Windows XP?

Tags: iis, windows-xp

For the project I'm working on I noticed that file transfer* speed is really bad if I'm using IIS FTP and HTTP services. I know that the last thing I should think is "it's a Windows bug", but the fact that simply by using IIS on Windows Server or by changing IIS on that Windows XP machine to FileZilla and LightHTTPd, my file transfer speeds go up twice from the original configuration, makes me go "hmmm".

Are there any limitation on IIS running on Windows XP? Any file transfer throttling or something like that?

**File transfer is being done using one connection to one file. My file transfer client is the only one client connecting to the PC.**

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

As other people have said, by default there is a 10 simultaneous connection limit for IIS 5 in Win XP. This can be increased to a maximum of 40 via the metabase variable setting script.

```
   cd \inetpub\adminscripts  
   cscript adsutil.vbs set w3svc/MaxConnections 40  
   iisreset
```

The first command changes directory to the IIS adminscripts folder. The second command runs a script that sets the MaxConnections value in the IIS metabase to 40 (the maximum allowed). The third command (iisreset) shuts down and then restarts IIS.

Answer (score 1):

There is a limit of ten concurrent connections. This can be increased to 30 using the IIS metabase editing tool.

You're probably better off using LightHTTPd.

Answer (score 1):

There is a 10 Simultaneous Connections limit...

Answer (score 0):

There is also a limit to one site.  Note that a site != to a Virtual Diretory/Application, so it's rarely an issue for a programmer.